# Proguard: how to solve error code 1?

Tags: android, proguard

I uncommented following line in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

And also replaced the libs of android-sdk with last version of Proguard (5.0).
When I try to export the apk, I see following error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Proguard Error 1 
Output: 
Note: there were 365 duplicate class definitions. 
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass) 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener 
Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Category 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Priority 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Hierarchy 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Hierarchy 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Hierarchy 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log.Logger 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextListener 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent 
Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find referenced class javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSName 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSContext 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.KerberosScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.NegotiateScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.auth.SPNegoScheme: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.ehcache.EhcacheHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.sf.ehcache.Element 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClientIF 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASResponse 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException 
Warning: org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.memcached.MemcachedHttpCacheStorage: can't find referenced class net.spy.memcached.CASValue 
Warning: there were 153 unresolved references to classes or interfaces. 
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. 
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress 
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options. 
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) 
Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes. 
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will 
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged. 
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency) 
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. 
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:222) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:97) 
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:507)
```

How to solve it? My proguard-project.txt is empty (a lot of line with # before lines). Thanks you ad advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the log itself you can see the solution

"**If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress 
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.** "

Try adding

**-dontwarn org.apache.****

similarly add other packages in proguard file